# pthread error code 3025 (ENOENT) on the as400/IBM i?

Tags: pthreads, ibm-midrange

When I have the following C source code, which is running on an IBM i Midrange, then I get a non-zero result from `pthread_create`, specifically 3025, which is ENOENT (No such path or directory), which doesn't make any sense to me. Anyone have any thoughts on what the error *actually* means in this context.

```
#define _MULTI_THREADED
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 520
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void* workerThread(void* parm) {
    // Do some work here
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  pthread_t t;
  int rc;
  rc = pthread_create(&t, NULL, workerThread, NULL);
  if (rc != 0) {
    char *msg = strerror(errno);       
    perror("pthread_create failed");   
  }

  // Other code here

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's 3025 and not 3029 - EBUSY?  I'd expect a 3029 if you tried to run in a single threaded job..

Comment: That was what I would expect, but it does appear to be 3025 (even in debugging).

Comment: Can you provide more info on how you are trying to run this program? I'm now wondering if you aren't having an issue with stdin, stdout, and stderr not being created in your environment when pthread_create runs.  My guess is that it's trying to copy your current io streams and failing because they don't exist or the program doesn't have access to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pthread_create` doesn't set `errno`.  You should be checking `strerror` of `rc`.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html

```
char *msg = strerror(rc);
```

Comment: Great, when I call the above code, I am getting "Resource busy", which I think is EBUSY, meaning I am running single threaded.